# Existe alguma função que verifique se um determinado valor esta contido num certo intervalo?

Tags: r, testes, condição

Supondo que:

```
x=120,00
limites.inferior<-80
limites.superior<-160
limites<-c(limites.inferior,limites.superior)
```

Estou realizando este procedimento com um teste lógico:

```
x.int<-x>=limites[1] && x<=limites[2]
```

Existe uma função que realize esta simples verificação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode obter o mesmo resultado fazendo uma comparação a menos.
Como explicado na [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13972533/3297472).

> the trick is to substract the middle between low and high from x, and then check whether that difference is less than half of the distance between low and high.

Traduzido em algo como: 
O truque é subtrair a metade da soma do limite inferior e do limite superior do número, e depois verificar se a diferença é menor do que metade da distância entre o limite inferior e o limite superior.

Em código você pode ter a seguinte função:

```
in.interval2 <- function(numero, li, ls){
  abs(numero-(ls+li)/2) < (ls-li)/2 
}

> in.interval2(120, 80, 160)
[1] TRUE
```

Em questão de tempo, comparando com a sua função:

```
in.interval <- function(numero, li, ls){
  numero > li & numero < ls
}

> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   in.interval(120, 80, 160),
+   in.interval2(120, 80, 160)
+ )
Unit: nanoseconds
                       expr  min   lq    mean median   uq   max neval cld
  in.interval(120, 80, 160)  708  709 1405.89   1062 1063 25836   100   a
 in.interval2(120, 80, 160) 1062 1416 2517.19   1417 1770 60872   100   a
```

E para vetores um pouco maiores.

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   in.interval(1:200, 80, 160),
+   in.interval2(1:200, 80, 160)
+ )
Unit: microseconds
                         expr   min    lq    mean median     uq    max neval cld
  in.interval(1:200, 80, 160) 6.725 7.079 8.20441  7.433 7.6095 33.268   100   b
 in.interval2(1:200, 80, 160) 3.186 3.540 4.49548  3.540 3.8940 20.528   100  a
```

Note que dessa forma vc é 30% mais rápido para comparar um número e 100% mais rápido p/ comparar 200 números.

Em termos de tempo, não acho que isso irá acelerar muito o seu código, uma vez que a unidade é microsegundos (10^-6s) para o vetor de 200. Ou seja, você tem que executar esta linha pelo menos umas 300.000 vezes para que essa mudança  acelere pelo menos 1s.

Answer (score 2):

O mais próximo que eu encontrei foi a função `findInterval`.

Você pode tentar algo como:

```
x.int <- (findInterval(x, limites, rightmost.closed = TRUE) == 1)
```

Mas sinceramente não vejo razão para você deixar de usar o teste que esta usando atualmente.

Comment: Esta condição está dentro de um Loop, quero verificar se isto deixa o processo mais rápido. Vou deixar a questão em aberto por mais algum tempo para ver se outras sugestões. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Essa resposta do SO pode ajudar. Ele faz um benchmark de varias formas. A forma que o Marcos colocou, em vetores grandes, pode aumentar em 2x a performance. Para vetores pequenos, não faz muita diferença. Na resposta, são apresentadas outras formas que aumentam em até 2x a performance p/ vetores pequenos tbm. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13972533/3297472